Correct capitalization of SDL2 add-on packages for CMake?
Building on a Mac with CMake, I am trying to use the various add-on packages that go along with SDL2:
sdl2_gfx, sdl2_ttf, sdl2_mixer, etc. Question: when dealing with these packages through homebrew, the capitalization is all lowercase. What is it in CMake? CMake uses
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
successfully. But then I'm trying things like
find_package(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED)
or
find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
without success. No error messages printed, but symbols that should be defined are coming up empty, such as
SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES.
What is the correct capitalization for these things in this context?
Here's the status with homebrew:

% brew list sdl2_ttf
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_ttf/2.22.0/include/SDL2/SDL_ttf.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_ttf/2.22.0/lib/libSDL2_ttf-2.0.0.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_ttf/2.22.0/lib/cmake/ (2 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_ttf/2.22.0/lib/pkgconfig/SDL2_ttf.pc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_ttf/2.22.0/lib/ (2 other files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_ttf/2.22.0/sbom.spdx.json

Here's CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(my-project)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED)
link_directories(${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_DIRS})
# include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}  . Library APClass Library/jpeg)
# -- didn't work, had to force:
include_directories(/opt/homebrew/include . Library APClass Library/jpeg)
message( STATUS SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS=${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message( STATUS SDL2_LIBRARIES=${SDL2_LIBRARIES} )
message( STATUS SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS=${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
message( STATUS SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES=${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES} )

add_library(Drawbox SHARED) 

add_subdirectory(Library)
add_subdirectory(Tools)
add_subdirectory(APClass)

target_compile_features(Drawbox PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
target_compile_options(Drawbox PRIVATE -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-writable-strings)

add_executable(Test Test/ClickDraw.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test Drawbox ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} SDL2_gfx) 

Here's the output I’m getting, similar with either capitalization. (I don't understand the warning, it seems to pertain to a layer that I don't control, and I don't know if it is a critical factor here)
[main] Configuring project: Drawbox 
[proc] Executing command: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang++ -S/Users/ken/prog24/Drawbox -B/Users/ken/prog24/Drawbox/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
[cmake] CMake Warning (dev) at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.29.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
[cmake]   The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (SDL) does
[cmake]   not match the name of the calling package (SDL2).  This can lead to
[cmake]   problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
[cmake]   (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   cmake/FindSDL2.cmake:198 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
[cmake] This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
[cmake] 
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2
[cmake] -- SDL2_LIBRARIES=/opt/homebrew/lib/libSDL2.dylib-framework Cocoa/opt/homebrew/lib/libSDL2main.a
[cmake] -- SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS=
[cmake] -- SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES=
[cmake] -- Configuring done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /Users/ken/prog24/Drawbox/build


As you could find from the CMake output, for process find_package(SDL2) CMake executes script cmake/FindSDL2.cmake. This is script shipped with your project, and only you know its content. BTW, the warning means that originally given script is expected to be called via find_package(SDL) (so it had a name FindSDL.cmake). Do you also have a script cmake/FindSDL2_ttf.cmake? If yes, then find_package(SDL2_ttf) uses this script, and you need to consult given script about the ways how it delivers its results to the caller.
